# Microsoft Access runtime error 2455 when trying to access grandchildren forms from child form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2003, grandchild

I have three forms in an Access 2003 database (developing in Access 2007) that sit in a parent -> child -> grandchild relationship.  In the 'Form_Load' sub of the child form, I set some properties of the grandchild (form header, row source, and control logic).  When I view the child form, everything works properly.  When I view the parent form, I get the error:

> Run-time error '2455': You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report.

in reference to the line:

```
Me.GrandchildFormName.Form.Foo.Caption = "bar"
```

I can access any property of the grandchild form *except* the Form property without throwing any errors.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?  I made a test case in a new database and it worked fine, so I'm leaning towards there being something in the legacy code I inherited with the database (which, I've been told, goes back 18 years to a pre-Access database system) that is causing the problem, but I figured I'd check here to see if any of you might know a work-around.

If it's relevant, the actual structure of the forms is a bit more complicated, with the grandchild form appearing multiple times (under different control names) in the child form, like this:

```
|--------------|
| A            |
|  |----------||
|  | B        ||
|  |  |------|||
|  |  | C[1] |||
|  |  |------|||
|  |          ||
|  |  |------|||
|  |  | C[2] |||
|  |  |------|||
|  |----------||
|--------------|
```

Eliminating all but one of the grandchild forms does not fix the problem.

I could probably write code to work around the problem if there was a way for the grandchild form to know which of the instances it is being loaded as, but as far as I am aware, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

I will use `Parent`, `Child`, and `GrandChild` for referring to the respective forms (not the data sources).

Generally the `Form` property of a subform control gets a "valid reference" only after the subform is shown. Thus, if you want to execute the code in `Child.Form_Load`, you have to make sure that `GrandChild` is visible when `Parent` opens.

**Solution**

Since I assume that in your case `GrandChild` is visible if you open `Child` (without opening `Parent`) but `GrandChild` is not visible when you open `Parent`, I would suggest the following solution without changing your UI:

Move the code of `Child.Form_Load`, which accesses `GrandChild.Form`, into `GrandChild.Form_Load`. Whenever `GrandChild` loads it can access everything from `Child` (`Me.Parent.Form`) or even `Parent` (`Me.Parent.Parent.Form`).

In other words `GrandChild` has to pull the information (from `Child` or `Parent`) and change itself instead of `Child` pushing the information down to `GrandChild` by changing `GrandChild`.

**Example:**

Let's say `Parent` has an 1:n relationship to `Child` and `Child` has an 1:n relationship to `GrandChild`. `Parent` presents `Child` as a datasheet thus `GrandChild` is not not shown when `Parent` opens. In this case any access to `GrandChild.Form` results in a *2455 runtime error* since `GrandChild` is not shown.

In this example each line of the `Child` datasheet would have a plus-symbol which allows to show `GrandChild`. Let's say you put a button on `Parent` which executes the code you currently have in your `Child.Form_Load` sub. Clicking on this button after `Parent` opens results in an error (see above), but if you click on one of the plus-symbols in `Child` and then click on the button the code would execute without the *2455 error* since in this case `GrandChild` was made visible before the `GrandChild.Form` access was executed.

Comment: It seems almost totally random which combination of Froms!FormNames or JUST the form name or both or an exclamation point or a period... you have to use to do what you want.

Comment: This is useful. I solved one of the 2455 errors by moving `Child` initialization code from the `Parent` back to `Child` (where it really belongs)
Now I just have to deal with another `Parent`/`Child` pair that is still throwing 2455, even after I applied the same fix that worked above! grrrr...

Answer (score -1):

Just above the line giving the problem type:
On Error Resume Next

Run it and that will solve your problem. After one run you can erase the line and will keep working.

Comment: This will work only under very particular circumstances, which seem not to be the general root case of the problem for the OP.