# Set Form Properties on SubSubform from the Main Form with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2007 (or 2010), I need to set the properties on a subform, embedded within the first subform, from the main form using VBA. To make it clear which form I'm talking about, I'll call the this form "subSubform" as I do in my code (well, subSubform is actually the name of the sub-subform control).

When the form loads I have a subform control on my first subform that's blank (does not contain a form source object). If needed, I fill out the SourceObject property of this control with the name of a valid form, as well as the LinkMasterFields and LinkChildFields properties. This all appears to work fine because I do get an expandable plus sign that otherwise wouldn't be there.

Next I try to set the RecordSource for the subSubform and I get an error:

**2455 You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report.**

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Me!subform1.Form!subSubform.Form.RecordSource = sSubformSQL
'and I've tried this with the same bad results
Me.subform1.Form.subSubform.Form.RecordSource = sSubformSQL
'and this too
Forms("frmQuery").subform1.Form.subSubform!Form.RecordSource = sSubformSQL

'And I've tried this. It fails too, on the last line with the same error:
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Forms("frmQuery").subform1.Form
    Dim frm2 As Form
    Set frm2 = frm.subSubform.Form
```

I've tried setting a timer and waiting one second to run the above code, just in case it takes some time for the form to load. But this makes no difference.

I've tried running code from the first subform instead of from the main form, but that doesn't help either. Still fails with the same error.

FWIW, both my subform and my subSubform are DataSheet views. I don't think that makes any different on what I'm trying to do here (although I'm well aware of the performance problems involved so don't scream at me).

I recognize that it's probably a very odd request. But I'm creating a dynamic query interface that needs this.

Any ideas how to set form properties on a subSubform?

Comment: See the notes below Albert's answer below for the actual answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you setting properites of a sub form. The format of:

me.subform1.form.subform2.form.RecordSource = sql

s+Should work just fine.

The problem is you are trying to nest a continues form (or datasheet) in side of a continues for (or a datasheet). This is NOT permitted.

The workaround is to simply place the two sub forms side by side and don’t' nest.

You can still get the second (child child) form to follow by using the link master settings.

In the link child/master settings for child 1, you place:

linkChildFields      main_id        (whatever is the name of the field in
this sub-form that is used to relate back to the parent table)
LinkMasterFields    [ID]

In the link child/master settings for child 2 form you place

linkChildFields      main_id        (whatever is the name of the field in
this sub-form that is used to relate back to the parent table)
LinkMasterFields    [child1].[form].[ID]   ("masterForm" is the name of
the control you used to hold the master form.

So you can model a many to many, but you cannot nest, but as noted the above gives you the same result anyway. So a form will look like this one:

[image]

You also likly in the on-current event of the left side (child 1), will want to place a requery of the right side when you navagate - as it often will not update automatic for you.

So:

```
me.parent.Child2.Requery
```

Comment: you must get up early. Thanks for your response. Actually, I'm not trying to nest continuous forms. I'm nesting datasheet views, which does work. Your suggestion is certainly a good work around, but I need views that are very large width-wise showing up to 20 or 30 columns at times. So having two views side-by-side is not going to work. Over-and-under would work better, but even that will take up too much real estate. I think I have found a work-around, where I put my code in the subSubform and run it on Form_Open or using the Timer and Global Variables.

Comment: Ok, it is important to note that when you nest datasheets that the sub form cannot be referenced UNTIL it is expanded.  So, yes you can next datasheets, but the expanded form (in your case the sub sub form) does not exist or more correct to state that an instance has not yet been created. So you have to use the on-open (or on-load). The load event fires the first time the user expands and hits + sign and I don't believe can program force this.

Comment: That answers my question. I just discovered the same thing within the last hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the `Form` property of a subform control gets a "valid reference" only after the subform is shown. Thus, if you want to execute a `subSubform.Form` access as you do in

> Me.subform1.Form.subSubform.Form.RecordSource = ...

you have to make sure that subSubform is visible before the access is executed. The easiest way to do it is to let the subSubform set it's source on his own while it loads (in it's Form_Load sub).

For further details and explanations see my answer in [Microsoft Access runtime error 2455 when trying to access grandchildren forms from child form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401501/microsoft-access-runtime-error-2455-when-trying-to-access-grandchildren-forms-fr) where the problem is the same.